# execve: how can I initialise char *argv[ ] with multiple commands instead of a single command?

Tags: c, linux, posix, pid

execve: how can I initialise char `*argv[ ]` with multiple commands instead of a single command?
If I want to execute 4 commands, can I use the following statement?

```
char *argv[4][ ] = { {...}, {...}, {...} };
```

And to execute them using execve, can I use a loop with a var from 1 to 4?

Comment: The `exec` family of functions is to execute *one* program only. You can't use them to execute multiple programs. Especially not through the `argv` array, which `exec` doesn't use to find the program to execute.

Comment: You will have to use a loop. `execve` will execute only the first program and treat the other commands as arguments to the first. You are right, you would have to use a loop.

Comment: Oh and remember to `fork` a new process in the loop, as a successful `execve` call will not return.

Comment: The tool for executing a batch of commands is the shell, so you could `execve()` `/bin/sh` with a proper argument list --- or as already stated, do yourself what a shell does (`fork()`, `execve()` and `wait()` ... or `posix_spawn()` and `wait()`)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, better said _is a system call designed only to load a program image in memory and start executing it_.  IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

You can not execute multiple commands with just one `execve` call. In a loop you will need to `fork` your program to execute multiple `execve` calls. In the [manpage of execve](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) it's written:

> execve() does not return on success, and the text, data, bss, and stack of the calling process are overwritten by that of the program loaded. [...]
>
> Return value
>   On success, execve() does not return, on  error  -1  is  returned,  and
>          errno is set appropriately.

**Method using fork:**

Output:

```
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3
```

Code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int idx;
   char *argv[][4] = { {"/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello 1", 0},
                       {"/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello 2", 0},
                       {"/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello 3", 0} };
   for (idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++)
   {
      if (0 == fork()) continue;
      execve(argv[idx][0], &argv[idx][0], NULL);
      fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

---

**Method using command concatenation:**
A workaround would be to concate the commands using the shell:

Output:

```
Hello 1
Hello 2
```

Code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char *argv[] = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello 1 && echo Hello 2", 0};
   execve(argv[0], &argv[0], NULL);
   fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Linuxknowledgeseeker if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The `exec*()` family of functions **replaces** the current running process with a new executable. So there's no way to execute multiple commands, because once you call `execve()`, your own program doesn't run any more -- the process is now executing the new program.

The existing answer shows the "classic" approach of using `fork()` to create a new process and calling an `exec*()` function there. This has a little overhead of copying some process-related resources that are immediately replaced again by the `exec*()` call. To solve this inefficiency, `vfork()` was invented. `vfork()` isn't supposed to do any of the copying and therefore, doing anything other than calling `_exit()` or one of the `exec*()` functions in a child created by `vfork()`is **undefined behavior**.

This is a huge source of bugs and was later removed again from the POSIX standard, so you *should not use `vfork()` in a modern program*. Nowadays, there's a new way to solve this problem: [`posix_spawn()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn). This function creates a new process directly with a new executable. As this is a good match for what you're trying to achieve in your question, here's a tiny usage example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <spawn.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

extern char **environ;

int main(void)
{
    char *argv[][3] = {
        { "echo", "First command", 0},
        { "echo", "Second command", 0}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        pid_t pid;
        if (posix_spawn(&pid, "/bin/echo", 0, 0, argv[i], environ) != 0)
        {
            fputs("Error spawning child.\n", stderr);
        }
        else
        {
            // could get exit code etc here, see
            // https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid
            wait(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In case the number of arguments for each command is different, how should we initialise it and call in the loop?

Comment: @Linuxknowledgeseeker the simplest method would be: fill up with more `0` values at the end, so they have the same length. Or maybe don't use a loop. Or use an array of `char **` instead of a 2d-array of `char *`. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Could you please post an example with char ** to execute 4 commands with variable number of arguments

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot.  Simply.  The `execve(2)` system call is not a call to execute several commands, but only to overwrite the space allocated by a process by loading a new program image into its virtual space.  This means the only way to execute several commands from `execve(2)` is to load a shell and make it execute several commands.  You have to understand that this means loading a program into memory and begin executing it, and not executing programs or shell scripts in general.  When you understand this, you'll be able to understand the reason of loading a shell to execute several commands in a row (like the below example or what the `system(3)` function call does)

```
execlp("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", "echo foo; echo bar", NULL);
```

for example, will execute two different echo comands which are passed to a `bash(1)` shell in a single parameter string.

## Note

I've used the similar `execvp(2)` system call for simplicity, but the same is applicable to the `execve(2)` (which is the full general system call interface, although both translate to the same `exec()` system call.